# Fecha y Hora de la Red (Java Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, activity

Como podría verificar desde código que la opción de **Fecha y Hora automáticas** esta activada en el dispositivo?

Si alguien conoce la solución le agradecería de antemano

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes detectarlo de esta forma `public boolean isActiveTimeAutomatic(Context context) { return Settings.Global.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.AUTO_TIME, 0) == 1; }`

Comment: Gracias estimado, Saludos desde Nicaragua

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar este método que funciona para todas las versiones de sistema operativo:

```
public static boolean isTimeAutomaticEnabled(Context context) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {            
        return Settings.Global.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.AUTO_TIME, 0) == 1;
    } else {
        //Menor a Android 4.2
        return android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.AUTO_TIME, 0) == 1;
    }
}
```

Lo puedes llamar especificando el contexto, ejemplo:

```
System.out.println("Automatic date & time enabled? " + isTimeAutomaticEnabled(getApplicationContext()));
```

Comment: Muy agradecido, lo implementare!!!

Comment: Lo acabo de implementar y funciono, muchas gracias Crack!!!

Comment: Excelente @AssielNahumReyesUmaña !, saludos!.